# Unknown format for big database dump ASCII file

Tags: sql-server, database, ascii, mysql

I have a big file (3GB) containing a database dump. The file extension is "bkp", but it's only a uncompressed ASCII file. Tables are described in this way:

```
    [TABLE="TABLE NAME"]
    [FIELD1], [FIELD2], [FIELD3]
    DATA1 -> DATA2 -> DATA3
    DATA1 -> DATA2 -> DATA3
    DATA1 -> DATA2 -> DATA3
    ....
    [END TABLE]
```

I have to import these data into a database engine (SQL Server or MySQL), but I don't know what the software used to generate this file is and if it's possible to use a software to import these data. Alternatively I could write a short script to do it, but I would appreciate a faster solution

Comment: why don't you decide which database engine you are using first.....

Comment: because I don't know yet... now I would like to know if this data structure is a standard, if there is a software to process it

Comment: But this is a real question... I would like to know if someone know this data structure, if it's a standard, if there is a software to process these data. I mentioned mssql and mysql because the engine is indifferent...

Comment: apparently, telling someone to make a decision on a RDBMS and then come back with a real question is enough to get your comment deleted.

Comment: With the right combination of skip rows, field terminator and row terminator you could import this data into a SQL Server database using the standard tools, i.e. bcp or bulk insert